# How can I get text to line symmetrically at a line break

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table that holds a links and a font awesome icon in it.

This bootstrap table is also in a bootstrap column. When the next is too long there is a line break and the text continues on the next line.

However I would like the text to start to continue where it is directly aligned under the text that is above.

Right now the text breaks and falls right under where the font awesome icon is to the far left.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="our-story-pt-6">
  <div class="container">
    <h4>More Information</h4>
    <div class="more-info">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="more-info-link">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a href="#">Life Sciences Overview</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a class="text-left" href="#">Transforming Research Operations Through Strategy and Technology Overview</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a href="#">Commercial Launch Overview</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a href="#">Webinar: Preparing Your Company for a Successful Commercial Launch</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a href="#">Supply Chain Management Overview</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="more-info-link">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a href="#">IT Strategy - Emerging Overview</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a href="#">IT Strategy - Established Overview</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a href="#">LS Information Management Overview</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                <a href="#">Case Studies</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end div.more-info -->
  </div><!-- end div.container -->
</div><!-- end div.our-story-pt-6 -->
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try put them in two `td`

Comment: Thanks for the response, however that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your  in separate div. This will force any overflow from the a tag to flow underneath the start of the a tag itself.

Comment: Wrap what in a separate div? I tried wrapping the icon and wrapping the div and the making the div inline, that didnt work so then I tried inline block and that didn't work either. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: give them a float: left

Comment: post a fiddle with your css